# Clothing piece stuck behind creature part. (Spore)

Tags: spore

I have a tiny mask stuck behind a creature part and i cant move it or refund it. Is there any way I can sell it or get rid of it? Undoing does not work, and I have already saved my game so quiting without saving wont work either. I circled where the mask is stuck.[image]

Comment: Have you tried playing with the vertebras? Try removing some and shrink them, maybe a little part of the mask will come out and it'll be enough to select it.